# Протестировать функцию из const

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Как в Jasmine протестировать данный код, а именно метод `getNumber()`?

```
const PageFactory = SuperClass => class extends SuperClass {

getNumber() {
.......
}
```

пробовал через

```
new PageFactory(null)
```

через просто

```
PageFactory.getNumber
```

пишет

> TypeError is not a constructor(evaluating 'PageFactory.getNumber())

или

> _pageFactory["default"].getNumber()

Comment: а ты понимаешь что именно делает указанный код?

Comment: Наследуется от класса переданного в параметрах и присванием переменной  PageFactory, можно передать superclass  а можно просто null или я что то не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, как разбирается выражение

```
new PageFactory(null)
```

`PageFactory` - это стрелочная функция, а стрелочные функции **не могут быть** конструкторами. И в текущей записи оператор `new` применяется к самой функции `PageFactory`, а не к ее результату.

Простой вариант, обернуть вызов функции в круглые скобки.

```js
const PageFactory = SuperClass => class extends SuperClass {

  getNumber() {
    console.log('get number', this.num);
  }
}
class S {
  constructor() {
    this.num = 10;
  }
}
(new(PageFactory(S))).getNumber();
```

С `null` [не все так однозначно](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/extends-null). При попытке использовать `null`, создать экземпляр будет не тривиально:

```js
class A extends null {
  getNumber() {
    return 20;
  }
}

new A();
```

Как можно заметить, будет брошено исключение.

Для того, чтобы все-таки создать экземпляр, нужно изменить функцию конструктора:

```js
class A extends null {
  constructor() {
    var _this = Object.create(new.target.prototype);
    return _this;
  }
  getNumber() {
    return 10234;
  }
}
console.log((new A()).getNumber());
```

Comment: да, не получилось с null и Object, поулчилось еще и с jasmine.createSpy('constructor');

Answer (score 1):

1. `extends null` - так себе идея. Используй `Object`.
2. У `new` при использовании скобок вызова приоритет не тот.

Надо так:

```js
const PageFactory = SuperClass => class extends SuperClass {
  getNumber() {
    return 42;
  }
}

var Constructor = PageFactory(Object);
var a = new Constructor(); // или new Constructor
console.log(a.getNumber());

var b = new (PageFactory(Object)); // обращаю внимание на скобки
console.log(b.getNumber());

try {
  var c = new PageFactory(Object); // ошибка: (new PageFactory)(Object)
  console.log(b.getNumber());
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: сейчас при печати console.log(a.toString()) печатает просто 'object', и первый и второй способ выдает ту же ошибку( var a, var b) такая же ошибка